# libGDX IntelliJ IDEA cannot access com.badlogic.gdx.Application

Tags: android, intellij-idea, libgdx, android-studio

I have created a project with **libGDX setup ui**. The
project works great in Eclipse but when I imported it in [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html), the 
android project MainActivity.java throws 4 exceptions:

```
java: cannot access com.badlogic.gdx.Application
class file for com.badlogic.gdx.Application not found

java: cannot find symbol
symbol:   variable super
location: class com.vestrel00.nekko.MainActivity

java: cannot find symbol
symbol:   method initialize(com.vestrel00.nekko.KFNekko,com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplicationConfiguration)
location: class com.vestrel00.nekko.MainActivity

java: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
```

Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So I've fixed my problem: I just added libGdx.jar files to my desktop and android projects.

**Solution:**

Right click on the project > Open Module Settings > Libraries > Small green button (New Project Library Alt+Insert) > Java > and then select libGdx.jar file. After that, you must include this library into your desktop and android projects.

Don't Close the window, select Modules > android > Dependencies > Small Green button > Module Dependency and select main project. Do the same for desktop and press Ok.

Thats all. All my projects work correctly now.

Here's a tutorial with images. It is explained how to run desktop project too.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWOmO.jpg

Comment: If you are using Flixel-GDX, also do the first step with flixel-core.jar